# ng g s nameService --module=module doesn't work in Angular 10

Tags: angular-cli

I try to add command line in my app angular use command line.

```
ng g s services/data --module=app.module --skipTests=false
```

but it doesn't work, I don't know why. Maybe use last version angular and command line is old so how to use the same command in Angular 10 and I know I can't just import service from service and put it in *app.module* at provider but I just need know the command line how to work.

The error is :

> unknow option : --module

Comment: `--module` is not a valid option when generating a service. See this: https://angular.io/cli/generate#service

Comment: Take a look at this https://angular.io/guide/providers#provider-scope